# Visit Toronto while on H1B

Tags: usa, canada, h1b-visas

I am currently on H1B and am planning to visit Toronto, Canada. The visa on my passport is expired by I have extended my I94. So my question is that if I go to Canada for a 5 night vacation, can I re-enter USA if I have my updated I94, I797 and passport.

Please do let me know. Am planning to go next year during the summer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can visit Canada or Mexico for up to 30 days without having to renew your visa, as long as your I-94 is still in status, under [*automatic revalidation*](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1218/~/automatic-revalidation-for-certain-temporary-visitors). (Note that *students* on F and J visas can *also* visit certain Caribbean islands under this program, but H visa holders can only visit Canada and Mexico.)

You should bring a copy of your I-94 with you, as it will speed things up with Customs and Border Protection, and the airline will need to see it in order to board you if you are flying.

The complete rules for automatic revalidation are available in CBP's [Automatic Revalidation Fact Sheet](http://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/auto_reva.pdf).

Also note that this does not exempt you from the requirement to obtain a visa for Canada, [if Canada requires a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) from people of your nationality.

Finally, a caveat: Automatic revalidation is not available if you are traveling on a passport from Iran, Sudan or Syria. In this case, you must either remain in the US, or renew your visa while outside the US.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am not from the mentioned continues, hence the caveat is not applicable to me.

Comment: @Soumya People from every country will read this question, because they will have similar circumstances. The answer is more useful to them, if they are from those countries. :)

Comment: Absolutely agree to the point. Vote up.